# There exists any theorem saying that every orientable compact 2-Manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

in my Introduction to Algebraic Topology course we defined orientable compact 2-Manifold as quotient spaces of two-dimensional shapes (so, following this definition, they appear to be just "abstract" topological spaces). Since it's possible to visualize them as subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$, i was wondering if there is a way to show that these "abstract" spaces can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every compact orientable 2-manifold admits an embedding into $\mathbb R^3$. (Indeed, this turns out to be true even without the compactness assumption, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358326/an-orientable-surface-that-cannot-be-embedded-into-bbb-r3)).

The statement about compact 2-manifolds follows e.g. from the classification of surfaces, which is a classic result for which there are by now many proofs. It says that any compact orientable surface is homeomorphic to a surface of the form $S_g^n$, the (standard) surface of genus $g$ with $n$ boundary components, which can be explicitly embedded into $\mathbb R^3$.

A very short proof of the classification of surfaces (assuming that you know that any surface admits a triangulation, which is shown e.g. in an appendix to Hatcher's textbook on algebraic topology), due to Zeeman, is described in [this note](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/ClassificationSurfaces.pdf) by Andrew Putnam. Alternatively, you can prove the classification (assuming smooth structures) using Morse theory.